# Heroku: Compiled slug size is too large (max is 300MB)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

It's been a while since I last pushed my Rails 3.2.13 app to Heroku.  Now the push is failing because of this error:  "Compiled slug size: 1423.7MB is too large (max is 300MB)".

The only solutions Ive found request me to reduce my slug size by reducing gems and such. There's not much I can do to reduce gems.  Why is Heroku limiting this push?  Is there a way around this?

UPDATE: I checked the file size for each file in my app and found that my 'public' folder had over 1.4GBs of data which consisted (in the 'uploads' subfolder) of carrierwave file uploads stored to the app before started using plugged Amazon S3.  So I created a '.slugignore' file and added '/public/uploads'.

Comment: are you using the .slugignore file to nix the things that aren't necessary, like tests, dummy data, large design files, etc?

Comment: What about assets size? Maybe will be better move the assets to Amazon S3 or to somewhere else.

Comment: The .slugignore file didn't reduce the file size.  Im using s3 for storage.

Comment: Is the slug size based on the entire app or is it just based on the changes that Im pushing?  Can I redo the app and try to push more often? Like I said, this problem happened after I made a lot of additions and added a lot of new gems to the app.

Comment: The slug is your whole app, not just the delta since last push. You should make sure you don't have large binary files such as assets etc in your git repository -- those you should move to s3 as mentioned above. If any of your gems have large static files (like IP/Geo databases, language databases, etc.) -- consider using alternative gems that can host those on s3 as well.